# How to delete recent projects from Brasero Disk Burner?

Tags: brasero

I burned a couple of things to dvd and the titles show up when you open up Brasero. Is there a way to delete them from it's history - I tried uninstalling it and then reinstalled it from the Software Centre but nothing had changed.

Comment: don't know will this work but
open terminal and write there
`sudo remove .brasero`
or replace .brasero with write .bras and hit tab

Answer (score 3):

Try opening /home/(username)/.local/share/recently-used.xbel and remove entries that correspond to what's listed in brasero.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a "brasero-session.log"  in your home folder. Delete it and the history will be deleted.

Also, in system settings -> Privacy -> Applications tab you can add the Brasero application and the system will not keep logs of its use (hopefully)

Last, if you want to remove brasero with uninstallation, try

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge brasero
```